# How to make equal card height in css?

Tags: css

```
   <div className={Styles.didslider}>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          {CardData.map((data, index) => (
            <div className={Styles.didslidecard} key={index}>
              <DidyouknowCard
                iconimage={data.iconimage}
                title={data.title}
                description={data.description}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </Slider>
      </div>
```

I need the didyouknowcard in the same height how to do that without giving static width and height based on dynamic content height need to match?

[image]

Comment: Is this flex? Then you can use `align:items: stretch`, see also the flex documentation : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: it's in the slider i can't use `display: flex,` If i add display flex didslider it doesn't display the slider content @Kokodoko

Comment: In that case you'll have to include your CSS, otherwise it's hard to see how your layout is built.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-height:...` attribute in css file for card's div class

Comment: That only works if you know the height of the highest card.

Comment: Yes that's right. I usually control height from chrome inspect elements for like this situations. But using this solution in general may cause some incompatible appearance in different card rows of page

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Card 1</h3>
    
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Card 2</h3>
    
    
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Card 3</h3>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you say, that you can't use flexes, try to use one of this methods:

1. Table display with using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` properties

```css
.card-group {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

.card {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 33.33%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Where was it consumed the most?</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ad adipisci architecto consequatur,
            corporis, cupiditate deleniti distinctio illo iste magni nihil odit officia porro quidem reiciendis
            reprehenderit similique voluptate voluptates.
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Where was it eaten the most?</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. Grid display with using `display: grid`, `grid-template-columns`, `grid-gap`:

```css
.card-group {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Where was it consumed the most?</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ad adipisci architecto consequatur,
            corporis, cupiditate deleniti distinctio illo iste magni nihil odit officia porro quidem reiciendis
            reprehenderit similique voluptate voluptates.
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Where was it eaten the most?</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

They both do the same height but in different ways, look what method will be better in your project.